# Django Model form: restricting selection to group

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I have an existing Model form in Django. 
The field I am interested in is the language_pairs model multiple choice field.
Here are some of the entries:

```
  {
"model": "projects.LanguagePair",
"pk": 1,
"fields": {
  "name": "English (en) - German (de)",
  "code": "en_de"
 }
 },
 {
"model": "projects.LanguagePair",
"pk": 2,
"fields": {
  "name": "German (de) - English (en)",
  "code": "de_en"
   }
  },
  {
"model": "projects.LanguagePair",
"pk": 3,
"fields": {
  "name": "French (fr) - English (en)",
  "code": "fr_en"
}
```

The form code:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('title', 'notes', 'url', 'content')
        language_pairs =   forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=LanguagePair.objects.order_by('code'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            initial = kwargs.setdefault('initial', {})
            initial['language_pairs'] = [t.pk for t in kwargs['instance'].language_pairs.all()]
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True, user=None):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)
        source_languages = set()
        if commit:
            if user:
                instance.user = user

            instance.save()
            instance.language_pairs.clear()
            for lang in self.cleaned_data['language_pairs']:
                source_languages.add(lang['code'].split("_")[0])
            if len(source_languages) !=1:
                raise ValidationError("You can only have one source language")
            for lang in self.cleaned_data['language_pairs']:
                instance.language_pairs.add(lang)
        return instance
```

My question is this the right place to raise a validation error if any of the source languages are different (set has more than one entry)?

Answer (score 0):

The right place to raise a validation:
Form validation happens when the data is cleaned. If you want to customize this process, there are various places to make changes, each one serving a different purpose. Go and read the doc...

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning